# Erro nas DLLs quando vai compilar

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, allegro

Studio:

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>

int main(void)
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

    if(!al_init())
    {
        return -1;
        display = al_create_display(800, 600);
    }

    if(!display)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

acontece esses:

> 'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17415_none_dad8722c5bcc2d8f\GdiPlus.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdva.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdva.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdag.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
>   'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'
>   The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xa98) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
>   The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1324) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
>   The program '[1704] Game.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

O que eles significam e como arrumar?

Fui em ***Tools → Options → Debugging → Symbols*** e selecionei a caixa ***Microsoft Symbol Servers***, porem agora acontece isso

```
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Lucas-PC\Desktop\Arquivos\Game\Debug\Game.exe',           Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17415_none_dad8722c5bcc2d8f\GdiPlus.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\comctl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll'
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdag.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdva.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Game.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdva.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdag.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiu9pag.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'Game.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xed0) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x988) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[3712] Game.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Quando tento executar ele abre o cmd, carrega os Symbols e fecha o cmd.

[image]Quando vou compilar meu no Visual

Comment: Sobre a duvida, você instalou o allegro para 64bits? Já tentou remover e instalar a versão 32bit/x86? - Nota: **Sempre** poste os códigos dentro da pergunta e não como links, lembre-se, links podem quebrar com o futuro e a pergunta assim não ter muito sentido.

Comment: Você está tentando compilar um código em C usando Visual Basic?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu errei, já corrigi a pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Esses *avisos* aparecem porque as *DLLs* do sistema não possuem um [arquivo de informações de depuração](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(vs.71).aspx) usado pelo Visual Studio. Como são *mensagens de aviso*, você pode ignorá-las, se você quiser corrigir, segundo [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954908/1608936), basta ir em `Tools` → `Options` → `Debugging`→ `Symbols` e selecionar a caixa `Microsoft Symbol Servers`.  Isso fará que o Visual Studio baixe automaticamente os arquivos necessários.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Editei minha pergunta conforme sua resposta.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Tente o seguinte: feche e execute o Visual Studio como *administrador*. Compile novamente.

Comment: Executei como administrador e mostrei na pergunta oque acontece quando executo.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Sim.. mas os avisos ainda aparecem?

Comment: Aparecem sim, executar como administrador não mudou nada.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Quando você execute sem ser administrador o programa roda? tem como editar a pergunta e colocar os avisos que aparecem agora (como *admin*)?

Comment: Não, abrindo normalmente ou com administrador acontecem as mesmas coisas, os avisos são os mesmos que editei anteriormente, ele apenas abre o CMD, carrega os Symbols, após isso ele fecha o CMD e da os avisos.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Então há algo. Se quando você executa como *admin* o VS o programa **roda** e quando não *admin* o programa **não roda**, algo deve ter mudado. Qual é a última linha que aparece nos avisos?

Comment: Você não entendeu, em nenhum dos casos o programa roda(o CMD não é o programa), a ultima linha do aviso é 
The program '[2972] Game.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: @LucasCarezia Bom, tente o seguinte então: Vá em *Debug*, clique em *Options and Settings*, e habilite a caixa *Enable source server support*. Certifique-se de ter feito o que foi postado na resposta, depois tente compilar novamente.